# JPA criteria query load entire table

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I feel like this is a silly question, but I can't find the answer.  I have a class as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DEMO_VARIABLES")
public class Variable implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1734898766626582592L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="VARIABLE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="DEMO_VARIABLE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VARIABLE_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="VARIABLE_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private long variableId;

    @Column(name="VARIABLE_NAME", nullable=false, length=50)
    private String variableName;

    @Column(name="VARIABLE_VALUE", nullable=false, length=500)
    private String variableValue;

    public Variable()
    {

    }

    public long getVariableId()
    {
        return variableId;
    }

    public void setVariableId(long variableId)
    {
        this.variableId = variableId;
    }

    public String getVariableName()
    {
        return variableName;
    }

    public void setVariableName(String variableName)
    {
        this.variableName = variableName;
    }

    public String getVariableValue()
    {
        return variableValue;
    }

    public void setVariableValue(String variableValue)
    {
        this.variableValue = variableValue;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a criteria query to load the entire table (ie "select * from variables").  I'd like to use a criteria query more for code consistency than anything else.  I get this exception though:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.validate(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:437
```

The query I am using is:

```
public List<Variable> loadAllVariables()
{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Variable> query = builder.createQuery(Variable.class);

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

I know that the exception means it wants this:

```
Root<Variable> variableRoot = query.from(Variable.class);
```

But without a Predicate I don't see how to get the Root object into the query?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am not sure, did I understood you right, but if goal is to choose fetch list of all *Variable* entities, then following is way to go:

```
public List<Variable> loadAllVariables() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Variable> query = builder.createQuery(Variable.class);
    Root<Variable> variableRoot = query.from(Variable.class);
    query.select(variableRoot);

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Difference is that *select* is used. All implementations do not implicitly use last call of from in place of select. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told as follows:

> Portable applications should use the select or multiselect method to
>   specify the query’s selection list. Applications that do not use one
>   of these methods will not be portable.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I was only familiar with using query.where() and giving it a Predicated based on the Root.  query.select() was the missing link.

Answer (score 8):

Working with the query and its root is really simple:
First get the root the way you described:

```
Root<Variable> variableRoot = query.from(Variable.class);
```

Afterwards, you have to tell the query what it should do with the root: select, in this case.

```
query.select(variableRoot);
```

After that, you can modify the query further with the `query.where(...)` function and such.
When you're finished, you are ready to run it with your

```
return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

More info in [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)